# Convert aggregate result into summary table

Tags: r

given this data frame that is the result of a sum aggregation on the data.
[image]

how to transform this into the usual table as the one result of `table` in order to plot it properly.

for more clear picture of the desired output, it should be something like this:

```
              Mountain Bikes          Road Bikes  
2005          130694                  708713  
2006          168445                  1304031   
2007          0                       56112
```

I even tried something silly like calculating the value individually then combining them. but it's still a data frame so it think of the first column to be values instead of headers.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Category, Year) %>%
  summarize(SUM = sum(x)) %>%
  spread(Category, SUM, fill = 0)
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Year `Mountain Bikes` `Road Bikes`
#   <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1  2005           130694       708713
# 2  2006           168445      1304031
# 3  2007                0       561122
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(Category = paste(c("Mountain", "Road", "Mountain", 
                                     "Road", "Road"), "Bikes", sep = " "),
                  Year = c(2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007),
                  x = c(130694, 708713, 168445, 1304031, 561122))
```